# Show Selected Options along with others in an Angularjs Dropdown

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am creating a bloggin software and I created a Angularjs dropdown as follows to select terms for the post

```
   <select multiple="multiple" name="terms" ng-model="post.data.attributes.term_ids" required>
             <option value="" disabled="" selected="">Tags</option>

             <option ng-repeat="term in terms | filter: { taxonomy: 'tag' } " value="{{term.id}}">{{term.name}}</option>
     </select>
```

This works fine when I create the post, but when I edit the post I want to also show the terms which were selected while creating the post.

i.e if the "term.id in post.data.attributes.term_ids" then the term must be selected in the dropdown. I have been reading the docs and other examples but I am not sure how to go about doing this any help will be apreciated.

Answer (score 0):

just use the [ngSelected](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngSelected) attribute:

```
<select multiple="multiple" name="terms" ng-model="post.data.attributes.term_ids" required>
             <option value="" disabled="" selected="">Tags</option>

             <option ng-repeat="term in terms | filter: { taxonomy: 'tag' } " value="{{term.id}}" ng-selected="post.data.attributes.term_ids.indexOf(term.id) > -1">{{term.name}}</option>
     </select>
```

or, a better way.. you could use [ngOptions](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngOptions). something like:

```
<select multiple="multiple" name="terms" ng-model="post.data.attributes.term_ids" required ng-options="term.name for term.id in terms | filter: { taxonomy: 'tag' } ">
</select>
```

Comment: they both don't work, I modified the second suggestion to  " <select multiple="multiple" name="terms" ng-model="post.data.attributes.term_ids" required ng-options="term.name for term in terms  | filter: { taxonomy: 'tag' } track by term.id ">
     </select>"  but I want the value of post.data.term_ids to be only term.id it contains the whole term

Comment: have you checked your data types? you might be comparing a string to an integer

Comment: post.data.attributes.term_ids is a list of integers, need to loop through it n then compare with term.id that seems to be the problem. Thanks for your help.